# Groovy date/time compare

Tags: groovy, date-format

I have this string got from JIRA as the date/time I need to compare which one is earlier:"21/Sep/12 2:01 PM". How can I do this in Groovy?

Thanks
Jirong

Comment: Could you edit the question and let us know what you have already tried to do. The more details the better.

Comment: I am new to Groovy. As an system admin, just try to do a quick script. The date/time output from JIRA is like this and I need to compare it to the current time.

Comment: Hi. Please check what is [on-topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and consider asking at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the requirements you have put down I assume that you already have the date somewhere in code (if not check out com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor). As for comparing the dates here is a short script and if you need more dates then just stack them up in an array and loop through them.

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.*;

    class DateTimeComparer
    {
        public Date convertDateTime(String element) throws Exception
        {        
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy HH:mm a");
            return dateFormat.parse(element);
        }

        public static String compareDateTimes(Date date1, Date date2)
        {
            if (date1.after(date2)) return "date1 is after date2";    

            if (date1.before(date2)) return "date1 is before date2";

            if (date1.equals(date2)) return "date1 is equal to date2";
        }           

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            DateTimeComparer dateTimeComparer = new DateTimeComparer();

            Date convertedDate = dateTimeComparer.convertDateTime("21/Sep/12 2:01 PM");
            Date today = new Date();

            String comparedDates = dateTimeComparer.compareDateTimes(today, convertedDate);

            println comparedDates;
        }
   }
```

​

​
​

Comment: That doesn't look like groovy.

Comment: @MichaelT You can verify it at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/